# Jackson annotation JsonFormat$Value json java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, jackson, json-deserialization, zoneddatetime

I am using `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.0` in my gradle project. Since adding `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.6.0` to my project build file I have been getting this exception while running my gradle project. Here is the stack trace of my error.

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat$Value.empty()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat$Value;
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
>     ... 117 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat$Value.empty()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat$Value;
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.(MapperConfig.java:50)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.(ObjectMapper.java:535)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.(ObjectMapper.java:452)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:553)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:57)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:187)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
>     ... 119 more Nested in
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter':
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat$Value.empty()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat$Value;:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat$Value.empty()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat$Value;
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.(MapperConfig.java:50)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.(ObjectMapper.java:535)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.(ObjectMapper.java:452)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:553)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:57)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:187)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1272)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:489)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.internal.JettyPluginWebAppContext.doStart(JettyPluginWebAppContext.java:112)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)    at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.internal.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:111)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.AbstractJettyRunTask.startJettyInternal(AbstractJettyRunTask.java:238)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.AbstractJettyRunTask.startJetty(AbstractJettyRunTask.java:191)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.AbstractJettyRunTask.start(AbstractJettyRunTask.java:162)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:227)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
>     at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)    at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I have used not used `@JsonFormat` in my class. But I do have `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer` annotations using two classes for serializing and deserializing my `ZonedDateTime` to and from Json in UTC. I am doing this Serialization and deserialization for first time so please give any suggestions.

Here is my gradle file code:

```
apply plugin: 'java' apply plugin: 'eclipse' apply plugin: 'jetty' apply plugin: 'maven' apply plugin: 'war'

ext {  springVersion = "4.2.4.RELEASE"  springSecurityVersion = "4.0.3.RELEASE" }

repositories {      mavenLocal()    mavenCentral()
     /* maven {
        url "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
    } */ }

configurations.all {    exclude group: "commons-logging", module: "commons-logging"    exclude group: "log4j", module: "log4j" }

dependencies {    compile 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.12'    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'    compile "org.springframework:spring-core:$springVersion"    compile "org.springframework:spring-context:$springVersion"
        compile ("org.springframework:spring-web:$springVersion"){
       exclude group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"    }    compile ("org.springframework:spring-webmvc:$springVersion"){
       exclude group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"    }    compile "org.springframework:spring-orm:$springVersion"    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:$springSecurityVersion" compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:$springSecurityVersion"
       compile "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.7.4"

   compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.6.Final"        compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.6.Final"    compile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0"    compile "org.javassist:javassist:3.15.0-GA"    compile "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.31"
       compile "org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.2"
       compile "commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.2.2"    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4"      compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.0'    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.0'    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.0'    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.7.0'

       compile "net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.6.9"    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:4.3.5.Final"    compile "com.h2database:h2:1.4.177"    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2" 
       testCompile ("junit:junit:4.12"){
        exclude group: "org.hamcrest"    }    testCompile "org.springframework:spring-test:$springVersion"    testCompile "org.easetech:easytest-core:1.4.0"    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3"    testCompile "com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.2.0"    testCompile "com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:2.2.0"
       testRuntime "org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.2"  }
```

Comment: if you are using spring webmvc you dont need to add jackson dependency again , spring mvc  has jackson core jars already

Comment: hi priyamal, actually if i use the jackson dependency inside the spring mvc  or spring webmvc then i might have a chance to run into an issue with the same error I am facing now..JsonFormat.Value.empty() method not found coz this particular method is defined for versions 2.7 and above. Thats why i have actually excluded the jackson jar inside the spring mvc and webmvc and defined them manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleared up my issue when I just tried running task - gradle clean. I think some old project dependencies were lingering around till now. It was just a matter of cleaning the project. The project works fine now. :)

Answer (score 17):

Check your project dependencies. You might be using incompatible library versions. The version 2.7 has the method empty() and the version 2.6 not.

http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.Value.html

http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7.0-rc1/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.Value.html

Try to upgrade to version 2.7.

Comment: Hi, Benat
I have actually tried doing that too..upgrading to version 2.7 but still I am facing the same issue. Now I tried to exclude the jackson dependencies inside other major spring dependencies like spring-web and spring-webmvc dependencies. Even after that I am having the same issue.

Comment: Check if the WAR file you are building have the libraries you expect to have.

Comment: ya my WAR file also has jackson dependencies of version 2.7...still the same issue

Comment: Put your graddle file at the question.

Comment: I have pasted the gradle file code along with the question

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative solution to the ones already given by @BeñatBermejo and @AkashRaveendran above.  I'm glad Akash was able to get his system to work merely by cleaning up his environment, but I found that to be insufficient in my case.

The error was coming from jackson-databind, which I had in my pom as version 2.8.1.  However, since I also have Spring involved, the jackson-databind dependencies, namely jackson-core, were still at 2.6.6.

All I had to do was remove the version specifier in my jackson-databind dependency.  When I did that, Maven used the version named by Spring, 2.6.6, instead, which did not include the call to the JsonFormat$Value.empty().

If you need some jackson 2.7+ functionality, you can try specifying the higher version of jackson-core and any other dependencies of the jackson artifact you are trying to use.

However, with Spring involved, I would either see if you can get by with the lower jackson version it names, or see if Spring may have released a new version that includes the newer jackson libraries.  Overriding Spring's dependency structure undermines one of the biggest reasons for using Spring in the first place: You get a more fully tested set of interrelated dependencies to build on right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

delete all jackson file from .m2 directory, make sure your all jackson pom i.e data-bind, annotation etc have same versions. if required downgrade your version i.e- jackson 2.7.3 working well rather than 2.10.3